# OpenCV installation stuck at 100% in Raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I am new to raspberry pi and trying to install open-cv. I followed all the steps in https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/ I got no error so far and completed the process till 100%. But now it is stuck at 100% and installation does not ends.

I have left it for more then an hour but no changes at all. I have already increased the swap size and decreased GPU memory consumption.

I think the output should be like

...
[100%] Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/python3/cv2.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
[100%] Built target opencv_python3

and ends the installation. But in my case it is stuck at

```
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_MatchTemplate_Demo
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_calcBackProject_Demo1
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_compareHist_Demo
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_periodic_noise_removing_filter
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_Smoothing
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_Threshold
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_Threshold_inRange
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_changing_contrast_brightness_image
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_HitMiss
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_Morphology_3
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_Morphology_1
[100%] Built target example_tutorial_motion_deblur_filter
[100%] Built target opencv_perf_superres
[100%] Built target`enter code here` opencv_test_superres
```

I don't think installation is complete yet because if I try to end it manually by ctrl+C it shows

```
^Cmodules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Interrupt
modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Interrupt
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:19567: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Interrupt
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:19465: recipe for target 'modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all] Interrupt
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Interrupt
```