# Error: "make: * [Makefile:163: all] Error 2" and "make: * [Makefile:163: all] Interrupt"

Tags: python, opencv

When i install opencv in Raspberry Pi 3, I always see some error:

```
[ 41%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/test/test_cvtyuv.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object 
modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/test/test_distancetransform.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_imgproc.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
^Cmake[2]: * [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/build.make:375: 
modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/test/test_cvtyuv.cpp.o] Interrupt
make[2]: * [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/build.make:388: 
modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/test/test_distancetransform.cpp.o] Interrupt
make[2]: * wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make[2]: * Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: * wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make[2]: * [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_imgproc.dir/build.make:401: 
modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_imgproc.dir/perf/perf_integral.cpp.o] Interrupt
make[2]: * [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_imgproc.dir/build.make:414: 
modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_imgproc.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o] Error 2
make[1]: * [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3330: modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_imgproc.dir/all] 
Interrupt
make[1]: * [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3248: modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_imgproc.dir/all] 
Interrupt
make: * [Makefile:163: all] Interrupt
```

And:

```
[ 41%] Built target opencv_perf_photo
[ 41%] Built target opencv_test_photo
make: * [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

How can i do to fix this error. Pls!!!

Comment: Somebody had the same issue few days ago [stackoveflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467445/opencv-installation-stuck-at-100-in-raspberry-pi) without answer for now

Comment: The error looks like you are running out of memory or something, do you see OOM killer in the system log?

Answer (score 0):

Go through with this link:
https://learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/

you can install OpenCV perfectly with out any error. but the problem was it will take lot of time to install.

I had used pi3 model B+ with 32GB class10 SD card for me it took more than 12 hours for complete installation.